# How to detect Google Chrome Developer tools using dark theme?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I started to develop tools in the extend of Chrome Extension in the Developer Tools (F12). [Extending DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools)

[But since Chrome added dark theme](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2016/02/10/google-chromes-developer-tools-are-finally-getting-a-dark-theme/) into Developer Tools, How can I detect whether if dark theme applies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome 54 and newer:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.themeName
```